# How to add OLSRD as part of the linux kernel compile

Tags: kernel, embedded-linux, adhoc

Ad-hoc networking running linux Debian on an arm processor using OLSRD.

I want to compile OLSRD package as part of my custom kernel so I can update my system.
How would I make it so that this will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

olsrd is already in [stable](http://packages.debian.org/stable/net/olsrd). just install it with `apt-get`.

In stable you'll find the 0.6.2-2.1 version and in testing/unstable 0.6.3-6.